# How do I add cue points in Sorenson Squeeze

Tags: flash, video, compression, flv

I can find tons of posts relating to all different aspects of working cue points in [Sorenson Squeeze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorenson_Squeeze) (a compression suite for video), but I can't for the life of me find one post or figure out how to add a cue point in Sorenson Squeeze.

I'm trying to add a cue point to a file that is going to be exported as an [FLV file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Video) (Flash Video).

Answer (score 0):

The answer comes in two parts besides knowing that cue points are called markers.

First, it depends on what Squeeze version you are using. I am using Squeeze 5.0 and the icon to add a cue point is just below the video display timeline on the right side [two back-to-back triangles with a plus sign]. When you click it, A "marker line" shows up in the settings location just below the presets you have selected for file compression. If you right click this marker line you can edit it. The icon next to the insert marker icon allows you to set a key frame or a chapter cue point (marker). A cue point shows us as an orange marker on the time line. The cue point is placed where the play head is when you clicked the cue point (marker) icon

The second part of the answer is related to the functionality of the markers (cue points). Sorenson, in the 4.3 to 6.0 versions, had problems with the functionality of the markers. I can't for example seem to get them to work in 5.0. But I am working in Visual Studio and playing FLV files created in Squeeze. But on an Adobe site, they also noted this problem when working with Flash.

Sorenson is now at version 9.0 and I should hope they have resolved the issue at this point.  The 5.0 help manual I have is most vague about their use.